# JPA result streams and underlying JDBC connections

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

It's pretty much evident what's happening when you call `getResultList()` on a `Query` instance - the framework obtains a JDBC connection from the pool and returns it when the list is ready.

What is not clear to me is how JPA handles connections during the `getResultStream()` calls. Does it wait till I get to the end of the stream and then return the connection to the pool? What if I don't? What if I obtain a `Spliterator` from the stream and stop iterating somewhere in the middle?

My only guess is that such connections are returned to the pool after a timeout. Which would mean that, depending on the timeout value, I might need a much larger value of open DB connections. If I'm right, how do I configure the timeout value, particularly with **Spring JPA**?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is it doesn't. You're supposed to wrap the returned stream in a 'try with resources' statement.

It seems that a lot of people don't realize that `Stream`s are actually `AutoCloseable` and whenever they hold on to resources like JDBC connections or file handles, it's the developer's responsibility to properly close them.